# symfony,when the form does not have this field

Tags: forms, symfony

```
class FormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('a')
            ->add('b')
            ->add('c')
            ->add('d');
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' =>'entity'
        ));
    }
}
```

html form field:

```
<form>
    <input name="a" value="a">
    <input name="b" value="b">
</form
```

When I submit the form, the c,d is set to null.
When the form does not have this field, I do not want to update c and d :)

Comment: Why are you adding fields to the `FormType` if then you don't want to use them? Maybe you have different use cases and you should consider adding the fields dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

insted of this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
      ->add('a')
      ->add('b')
      ->add('c')
      ->add('d');
}
```

use this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   $builder
      ->add('a')
      ->add('b')
      ->add('c', TextType::class , array('mapped' => false))
      ->add('d', TextType::class , array('mapped' => false));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your buildForm function like this. In The Symfony FormType, by default all fields are required.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('a')
                ->add('b')
                ->add('c',TextType::class, ['required' => false,'empty_data' => null])
                ->add('d',TextType::class, ['required' => false,'empty_data' => null] );
        }
```

If you want to persist the entity in database c and d must be nullable as well